# Nougat (25.0.0)compilation warning

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am using UrbanAirship 8.0.2 in my app and I want update app compilation in 25.0.0 but it shown the warning due to urbanAirship used 24.2.1 support-v4 library and Google Play services 9.4.0. I have also tried UrbanAirship latest version 8.3.1, but Google Play services 9.8.0(not compatible for 25.0.0). Due to some new features, My App requirement is Google play 10.2. When I added Google play 10.2 and support 25.0.0 then build.gradle show the warning "your app is using multiple version of support v4 lib and different Google play versions thats may be lead the cause of app crash". Please suggest me whats is the best approach to resolve the issue?.

Comment: you can wait till UrbanAirship updates their SDK, and use old 24.2.1 sdk untill that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Define the newer dependencies to avoid a mismatch:

```
// Support libs
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'

// Urban Airship pulls in GCM, so define the newer version
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'

compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.3.2'
```